# Bot Framework FormFlow: Adaptive cards in carousel

Tags: botframework, formflow, adaptive-cards

I would like to display a set of adaptive cards in carousel. How this can be achieved? I our application we use DescribeAttribute in FormFlow to display items in carousel view, but now we want to switch to adaptive cards and I am trying to find out how to make it work together.

```
public static IForm<Model> FullForm()
        {
            return new FormBuilder<Model>();
                .Field(new FieldReflector<Model>(nameof(articleId))
                    .SetType(null)
                    .SetActive((state) => true)
                    .SetDefine(createFullChoice)
                )
                .Confirm("", state => false)
                .Build();
        }

        public static async Task<bool> createFullChoice(Model state, Field<Model> field)
        {
            field.RemoveValues();
            var articles = state.service.getArticles();
            var counter = 1;
            foreach (var article in articles)
            {
                article.name = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(article.name);
                var description = new DescribeAttribute($"{name}", "http:" + article.imageUrl, counter.ToString(), article.name, article.packing);
                field
                    .AddDescription(article.id, description)
                    .AddTerms(article.id, article.name, article.id);
                counter++;
            }
            return await Task.FromResult(true);
        }
```

Comment: Please post what code you're working with.

Comment: You can put adaptive cards in a carousel.  But, I see no built in way to use Adaptive-Cards with FormFlow.  Maybe this is something the Bot Framework will support in the future.  You can add a feature request on GitHub: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues

Comment: Maybe defining the form using a custom json schema: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-formflow-json-schema

Comment: ok, thank you so much!

Comment: You could also use the .prompter, and add an adaptive card directly.  Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52371573/adaptive-cards-as-formflow-prompts?rq=1